# creating a webservice in flask that queries a Mysql database and returns json

Tags: python, mysql, json, docker, flask

Please help:
I am trying to create a webservice in flask (this is my first time) that takes a str, queries an external mysql database and returns 1 row as json.

I am sure there are other of issues with the code below (all suggestions much appreciated), but I cannot even see them yet, because when I try to access example.com/webservice/vin/ I get "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." from nginx.

PLease can someone guide me where I am going wrong?

example.com return Hello from app_name running in docker...yayy. Its the other route that isnt working.

```
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
import json

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'xxx'
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():

    # Use os.getenv("key") to get environment variables
    app_name = os.getenv("APP_NAME")

    if app_name:
        return f"Hello from {app_name} running in a Docker container behind Nginx!"

    return "Hello from Flask"




@app.route('/webservice/vin/<vin>', methods=['GET'])
def get_vehicle(vin):

   sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` where column = '(%s )';" %(vin)

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    cur.execute(sql)

    row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row headers
    rv = cur.fetchall()

    json_data=[]

    for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
    return json.dumps(json_data)


from flask import make_response

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?  You mention an nginx proxy, is its configuration important to the question?  I'd suggest first trying to make the entire application work without Docker involved, both to minimize the number of parts involved and so that you're not trying to work around Docker's filesystem isolation.

Comment: Internal Server Error
When I enter example.com I get the successful message " "Hello from 'webservice' running in a Docker container behind Nginx!"
It is only when I put example.com/webservice/vin/<some number> that I get the error: "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: It is a very big database (10 million rows), maybe this is the problem?