# Connecting to remote mySQL database with docker, nginx, flask and uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am trying to build a simple webservice with flask. I have a docker network with nginx as reverse proxy, and this works to make flask return html as long as I am not asking for a  parameter (see this post: [creating a webservice in flask that queries a Mysql database and returns json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879807/creating-a-webservice-in-flask-that-queries-a-mysql-database-and-returns-json)). I have been reading a lot before posting this question and suspect it's got to do with the uwsgi config ( that part I understand close to nothing about). Please can anyone help?

this is app.ini:

```
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :5001
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=Flask_webservice
    expose:
      - 5001

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

docker logs flask returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./app/views.py", line 45, in Authenticate
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flaskext/mysql.py", line 59, in connect
    return pymysql.connect(**self.connect_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 1/2] 87.196.211.109 () {42 vars in 1930 bytes} [Sat May 23 17:37:10 2020] GET /Authenticate?Username=jay&Password=jay => generated 0 bytes in 27 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: In your container, there's no MySQL to connect to on localhost. This isn't an Nginx or Uwsgi error.

Comment: THank you AKX. I am starting to realize the problem is there (but still havent solved it) But what I dont understand is: Im trying to connect to a managed database on DO. Would I still need mysql in the container/ network ? cant I just specify the external database host in my flask-mysql config?

Comment: Yes, you'd specify the database host in your app config, but as it is, you've configured it to try and talk to `localhost`.

Comment: Where would I change that?

Comment: Well, you seem to be manually connecting to your database (`cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()`), so probably in that call.